# Microsoft's REST API's

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am working on integrating Outlook's calendar REST API with my personal system.
Using the authorization code grant flow, I am able to get a user to login to an application that I have registered in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. Once a user has logged in successfully, I receive a code on my redirect URL. Using the code, I fetch his bearer token (basic oAuth code flow).

Now, the confusion is with their documentation. They have 3 types of API, o365, outlook.office and graph. I am using their graph API for the calendar resource.
I'm using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview to fetch events from the primary calendar, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events to create events in the primary calendar and https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$batch for batch requests.

There are some scenarios that I want to cover here. When a user changes his/her outlook password, I need the user to re-login to the app so I can use a valid bearer token. From outlook [documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-office-365-exchange-online/), it looks like the refresh token becomes invalid as soon as the user changes the password (search for *refresh tokens become invalid*); which means, at the worst case, I can use the bearer token for an hour (default) to authenticate the API's.

> Is this normal of an oAuth flow? I always thought the bearer token would become invalid when a user changes the password.

Since I am working in an organization, I want my application to only be accessible by AD users in my organization.The application manifest has a field called availableToOtherTenants, which is defaulted to true. I changed the field to false so that only the users belonging to the organization AD can access it. But it looks like I am able to login to the application with my personal outlook account as well; in spite of this change.

> What am I doing wrong here? Am I doing the right this by registering
>   an application in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com?